# Add colors to chat systam

Tags: php, html, colors

I have a chat system on my site. i wanna be able to add colors for the users to chat. for some reason i am failling can anyone tell me what i am doing rung?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
```

This was the how it was organly till i changed it.

```
 $text = $_POST['text'];
```

The problam was when i did somthing like this in the chat `<b>whatever</b>` the out put would not come out bold just text like `<b>whatever</b>` so i tryid this $red = 'red' so when i tryd that nothing came out at all. no text no nothing. 
i am curintly trying something like this.

```
$textstart =  <font color=';
$red = red;
$green = green;
$blue = blue;
$textend =  '>   $_POST['text']   </font> ";
$textcolor = $textstart  $colorme  $textend ;


// Write to chat on post
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<font color='green'><div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A j-m").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: </font>".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($textcolor))."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);
```

I need the output of $textcolor in ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($textcolor))." to be like  $textcolor

This is how the output will be $textstart red $textend

Comment: Your date and name are always green, the message has no value in `color`.

Comment: Yea i know umm just updated the code. hope you understand what need to be done :) thanks

Comment: What about it? It would also help if you said what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok so oragnaly when i only use $text = $_POST['text']; add typt somthing like this in the chat <b>text</b> the out put would not be bold it would be just text. so i did was $red = <font color=red> so when i would type it in the chat $red it shuld work but it did not

Comment: That's because you still filter it out with `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Can i ask if i take out htmlspecialchars will it be easy to hack my site with some code a user can type?

Comment: Yes. Just use a ready-made chat system. They are out there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45636/discussion-between-avrumi-sherman-and-bart-friederichs)

Comment: fopen is very insecure. that's just asking to be hacked.